# QMessageBox delete on close

Tags: c++, qt, qmessagebox

I have a question that has obvious answer for some of you, but I just can't figure it out.

QMessageBox http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmessagebox.html has 2 ways of being displayed, either you do `exec()` which stop the program execution until user close the message box, or `show()` which just display the box (probably in separate thread or in some way that allows program to continue while box is waiting for user).

How do I delete the box after I use show()?

This code immediately close it, message box appears for nanosecond and then it's gone:

```
QMessageBox *mb = new QMessageBox(parent);
mb->setWindowTitle(title);
mb->setText(text);
mb->show();
delete mb; // obvious, we delete the mb while it was still waiting for user, no wonder it's gone
```

this code does the same

```
QMessageBox mb(parent);
mb.setWindowTitle(title);
mb.setText(text);
mb.show();
// obvious, as we exit the function mb which was allocated on stack gets deleted
```

also this code does the same

```
QMessageBox *mb = new QMessageBox(parent);
mb->setWindowTitle(title);
mb->setText(text);
mb->show();
mb->deleteLater(); // surprisingly this doesn't help either
```

So how can I use show() properly, without having to handle its deletion in some complex way? Is there something like `deleteOnClose()` function that would just tell it to delete itself once user close it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` flag

```
QMessageBox *mb = new QMessageBox(parent);
mb->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);
mb->setWindowTitle(title);
mb->setText(text);
mb->show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a 'delete on close' concept in Qt, so you can configure your message box to follow such behavior:

```
mb->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following:

```
QMessageBox* msg = new QMessageBox;
msg->setWindowTitle(title);
msg->setText(text);
connect(msg, SIGNAL(done(int)), msg, SLOT(deleteLater()));
msg->show();
```

that way it will destroy when it gets closed and when the event loop has nothing else to do.